# Why is variable set in scope of outer subscription changing when inner subscriptions changes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, state

I have the following angular 6 code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const stuffId: string = params.stuffId;

        this.service.getState().subscribe((state) => {
            if (stuffId) {
                const specificStuff: Array<Stuff> = state.stuff.filter((s) => s.id === stuffId);

                const specificState: State = {
                    stuff: specificStuff,
                    tableData: this.service.getTableModel(specificStuff),
                    chartData: this.service.getChartModel({ stuff: specificStuff }),
                    hasAssetId: true,
                };

                this.data = specificState;
            } else {
                this.data = state;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Where this.service.getState() observable may get new data multiple times but this.route.queryParams will not get new data unless the query params change

However, I am seeing by setting debug breakpoints that when query param 'stufId' updates, the initial value of 'stuffId' is what I would expect (a UUID) but when the inner subscription (the state service) updates the 'stuffId' value in the outer scope becomes 'undefined' - then another state update repopulates it with the id again. This is causing a 'stutter;' in the view.

I do not understand how the outer scope is getting changed by the inner scope since 'stuffId' is never accessed by the inner scope. Some rxjs thing I don't understand or something?

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, can you  reproduce it in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2un8ba?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: by the way don't subscribe in a subscribe - combine them using  https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand how the outer scope is getting changed by the inner scope since 'stuffId' is never accessed by the inner scope. Some rxjs thing I don't understand or something?

That is because `this.route.queryParams` emits a value more than once.

Each time a value is emitted a **new** subscription is made to `this.service.getState()` and overtime the inner `subscribe()` will trigger *overlapping* debug breaks. From the perspective of the debugger you might not realize you're debugging two or more subscriptions at the sametime.

Since you do this `this.data = state` or `this.data = specificState` the view template is *flickering*.

I recommend you learn about using `switchMap` and the `mergeMap` operators in Rxjs instead of calling `subscribe` from inside another subscription. You should only call an inner subscribe for a short lived observable that will complete.

```
this.route.queryParams
    .pipe(
        map((params: Params) => params.stuffId),
        switchMap(stuffId => combineLatest([
            of(stuffId),
            this.service.getState()
        ])),
        map(([stuffId, state]) => {
            if (!stuffId) {
                return state;
            }
            const specificStuff: Stuff[] = state.stuff.filter((s) => s.id === stuffId);
            return {
                stuff: specificStuff,
                tableData: this.service.getTableModel(specificStuff),
                chartData: this.service.getChartModel({stuff: specificStuff}),
                hasAssetId: true,
            };
        })
    ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```